# Making a list of hypothesis and references to the hypothesis

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, theorems, ntheorem

I have some problems with making a list of hypothesis and references to my hypothesis.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, makeidx]{memoir}
    \usepackage{ntheorem}


% *************** hyperlinks in PDF documents ***************

\ifpdf
    \pdfcompresslevel=9
        \usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,bookmarksnumbered,%
        colorlinks=true,%
        linkcolor=black,% 
        citecolor=black,%
        filecolor=black,%
        pagecolor=black,%
        urlcolor=black,%
        pdftex,%
        unicode]{hyperref} 
    \input supp-mis.tex
    \input supp-pdf.tex
    \pdfimageresolution=600
    \usepackage{thumbpdf} 
\else
    \usepackage{hyperref}
\fi
    \usepackage{memhfixc}

% *************** Hypothesis ***************
\newtheorem{hypo}{Hypothesis}[chapter]
\newtheorem{hypolist}{Hypothesis}[chapter]


\newcommand*\hypothesis[1]{%
   \stepcounter{hypolist}%
    \addtheoremline{hypolist}{#1}%
  \begin{hypo}#1\end{hypo}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{} 
    \hypothesis{Name were we at hope. Remainder household direction zealously the unwilling bed sex. Lose and gay ham sake met that. Stood her place one ten spoke yet. Head case knew ever set why over. Marianne returned of peculiar replying in moderate. Roused get enable garret estate old county. Entreaties you devonshire law dissimilar terminated. }

\chapter{} 
\hypothesis{Name were we at hope. Remainder household direction zealously the unwilling bed sex. Lose and gay ham sake met that. Stood her place one ten spoke yet. Head case knew ever set why over. Marianne returned of peculiar replying in moderate. Roused get enable garret estate old county. Entreaties you devonshire law dissimilar terminated. }


So by colonel hearted ferrars. Draw from upon here gone add one. He in sportsman household otherwise it perceived instantly. Is inquiry no he several excited am. Called though excuse length ye needed it he having. Whatever throwing we on resolved entrance together graceful. Mrs assured add private married removed believe did she. \

So by colonel hearted ferrars. Draw from upon here gone add one. He in sportsman household otherwise it perceived instantly. Is inquiry no he several excited am. Called though excuse length ye needed it he having. Whatever throwing we on resolved entrance together graceful. Mrs assured add private married removed believe did she. 


\clearpage
\chapter*{List of Hypothesis}
\listtheorems{hypolist} 

\end{document}
```

It seems that `hyperref` in combination with `ntheorem` cause unwanted references in the hypothesis list. The list of hypothesis contains a reference to the chapter (chapter 1) and the hypothesis number (hypo 1.1.) following the hypothesis. If a remove the `hyperref` package the list of hypothesis appears as I want it to be.

Q1: how can I get a list of hypothesis without the chapter ref. and hypo ref. following the hypothesis, without removing `hyperref`?

Q2: how to refer in the text to the hypothesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to load

```
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
```

and to use `\refstepcounter{hypolist}` rather than `\stepcounter{hypolist}`.

If you want to set references to your hypotheses, I suggest to add an optional argument:

```
\newcommand*\hypothesis[2][]{%
  \refstepcounter{hypolist}%
  \if!#1!\else\label{#1}\fi
  \addtheoremline{hypolist}{#2}%
  \begin{hypo}#2\end{hypo}
}
```

so that you can say

```
\hypothesis[foo]{Text}
```

and then `\ref{foo}` will refer to the number of the hypothesis.

By the way, your input has some glitches.

1. `makeidx` is not an option for `\documentclass`
2. `thumbpdf` is not necessary, unless you use a very old PDF previewer that can't generate thumbnails on the fly.
3. Inputting `supp-mis.tex` and `supp-pdf.tex` shouldn't be necessary.

---

A different solution allows for a better input:

```
% *************** Hypothesis ***************
\newtheorem{hypoin}{Hypothesis}[chapter]
\newtheorem{hypoaux}{Hypothesis}[chapter]
\usepackage{environ,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\addtohypolist{\addtheoremline{hypoaux}}
\NewEnviron{hypo}{%
  \refstepcounter{hypoaux}%
  \expandafter\addtohypolist\expandafter{\expandafter\ignorespaces\BODY}
  \begin{hypoin}\BODY\end{hypoin}
}
\patchcmd\listtheorems
  {\begingroup}
  {\begingroup\let\label\@gobble}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

If you change your code with this one, then your hypotheses can be input in the following way:

```
\begin{hypo}\label{foo}
This is one of the hypotheses.
\end{hypo}
```

and you can reference to it with the usual `\ref{foo}`.

Comment: Thanks a million for the solution and for pointing out the glitches. That `makeidx` is not an option for `\documentclass` surprised me. I thought I need it to make a `.idx`. I used to thumbpdf in case of.

Comment: @Adam It's `\usepackage{makeidx}` and then `\makeindex` if you want to make an index. Using `thumbpdf` is just a waste of time, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks and your right the `thumbpdf` is a waste of time.